# CentOS 5.4 and Rubyworks -- its getting old

Tags: ruby, centos

The Rubyworks repository is a great solution to getting a newer version of the ruby stack installed on CentOS, however, its beginning to show its age with ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111)...

Are there other repos or up-to-date packages already built for CentOS out there or must I resort to compiling from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this repo that seems to be well maintained: `http://rbel.frameos.org/`

To install ruby 1.9 the way it would get updated by yum on my CentOS 5.6 I did:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://rbel.co/rbel5
# yum install ruby19
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question some weeks ago, but my solution is to compile ruby 1.9 from source. It's really easy and doesn't need tons of deps.

You need only those two commands :

- `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
- `yum install readline-devel`

Then compile `rubygems`, there is really cool tutorials on Internet.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any actual problems compiling from source, I'm just looking for packaged solutions that are maintained and regularly patched so that "yum upgrade" keeps things moving forward from a security standpoint.  Also, when compiling for source, its easy to compile incorrectly for the platform and thus end up with wrong threading libraries or other such artifacts that can be sub-optimal compile for the platform.  Also a "feature" would expect of the package solution.